# Vite 4.2 HTML Env Replacement doesn't work with vue3.js

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, vite

According with the VITE v.4.2, the [html-env-replacement](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#html-env-replacement) should works directly into HTML code:

> Vite also supports replacing env variables in HTML files. Any properties in import.meta.env can be used in HTML files with a special %ENV_NAME% syntax.

Not in my case.

If I try it in composition API, it works, and it returns both variables.

```
setup(){
    console.log(import.meta.env.MODE)
    console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_RAGIONE_SOCIALE)
}
```

But, if I try it into the HTML code i don't:

```
   <h1>Vite is running in %MODE%</h1>
```

it returns: `Vite is running in %MODE%`

My configuration is:

```
 "vue": "^3.2.47",
 "typescript": "~4.5.5",
 "vite": "^4.2.1"
```

How can I fix it? Could be Typescripts the issue?

Ps. I understand there is the old school, but I'll prefer using the new Vite option reported into the first link.

Comment: You need to put your 'mode' in a let and use it in your HTML. `let mode = import.meta.env.MODE` then use it in your html in the classic way : `<h1>Vite is running in {{ mode }}</h1>`

Comment: If you really want to use it with the vite syntax you need to prefix it with VITE_ : [Prefix vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files)

Comment: Thanks @Samuel, as i wrote  in VITE v.4.2 "Any properties in import.meta.env can be used in HTML files with a special %ENV_NAME% syntax"

Comment: @Uncoke, have you solved this issue? if yes, then please share it with us. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @CodingbyRaj. No, sorry.  I used static variables instead of ENV variables. Please if you solve the question add answer here. I'll appreciate.